# React parent pass children will trigger rerender without state/props change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

When I have some children(HTML dom) as props to a child component and control in parent, I found that will trigger rerender!

Why React parent pass children will trigger rerender without state/props change?

How to avoid it? Check following.

```
const InsideChild = React.memo(({children}) => {
  const countRef = useRef(0)
  countRef.current += 1

  return (
    <div>render count: {countRef.current} {children}</div>
  )
})
                        
const OutsideParent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <div>
        Test1:
        <InsideChild />
      </div>
      <div>
         Test2:
         <InsideChild>
           <p>children as html dom will not trigger rerender.</p>
         </InsideChild>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

as sample code, Test1 will not trigger rerender, Test2 will. Is that possible to avoid it?

More detail and working sample here:

https://codepen.io/sky790312/pen/QWqygxQ

Comment: Memoize it : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `React.memo` is not working when you are sending **html** is becuase you the children is an object in that case, the only way you can compare it is with a deep compare or something.

You can add a comparer function to your memo, and compare the inner props of the objects in the case you send an html.

In the example i just check if the props are an object and then compare the object inside, hope it helps you

```
const comparisonFn = (prevProps, nextProps) => { 
  if(typeof prevProps?.children === 'object') {
    return prevProps?.children.props.children == 
      nextProps?.children.props.children
  } else {
    return prevProps?.children === nextProps?.children;
  }
}

const InsideChild = React.memo(({children}) => {
  const countRef = useRef(0)
  countRef.current += 1

  return (
    <div>render count: {countRef.current} {children}</div>
  )
}, comparisonFn)
```

Comment: Got it, I know what happen now. Thanks. I seldom to see project handle like this, should I handle it?